# I received an achievement twice

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog, yearling-badge

Today I jumped on stack exchange to find I've been awarded the Security Exchange Yearling achievement that I was already awarded yesterday.

[image: Awarded Twice]

I assume this is a bug?

Comment: No bug. Note the different icon color: one is for the main site, one for the meta site. Congrats! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's no bug.  One of the badges is grey, which means it's a badge for the Meta site.

Check your badge page and you'll see one for main, one for Meta.

You'll get one badge per side of the fence each time you earn more than 200 reps. So if you don't post so much on the Meta site, you might get less Meta Yearling badges than main site Yearling badges.

Comment: That makes sense. I did check my badge page and I actually see 3. Is that normal? https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqiuwy8kpq3bk4y/Screenshot%202018-11-07%2009.00.03.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, you earn a new one each year.

Comment: For each year where you get at least 200 rep. Years with less than 200 rep won't give a badge.